# Помогите с циклом for в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Только начинаю изучать Python, перешел на IDE PyCharm.
Пытаюсь разобраться с циклом `for`, выдаёт ошибку

> (Indentation Error: expected an indented block).

Сам код выглядит так:

```
family = ['aphelion', 'maksim', 'puma']
for people in family:
print(people)
```

Comment: А прочитать ошибку не получилось?

Comment: Какой вывод вы хотели получить?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка находится в самом цикле. Тут как и с функцией - нужен отступ.

```
for people in family:
    print(people) #Ошибка была тут, отсутствовал отступ.
```

Рекомендую к прочтению про [циклы](https://python-scripts.com/loops-for-while)

Answer (score 1):

```
family = ['aphelion', 'maksim', 'puma']
for people in family:
    print(people)
```

Ошибки всегда более чем информативны, не забывайте отступы, python к ним очень чувствителен.

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдет вот такая конструкция:

```
family = ['aphelion', 'maksim', 'puma']
for i in range(len(family)):
    print(family[i])
```